# What is the difference between a( ) and a[ ] in FORTRAN?

Tags: variables, fortran, fortran77

I am trying to understand a piece of FORTRAN code and need to understand the variables in this statement.

```
COMMON/THRM/AMGAS(6),VTMB[6],TCFMX
```

Q. I understand that these are global variables for block THRM but what is the difference between :

```
1.AMGAS(6)                 #note the curved braces
2.VTMB[6]
3.TCFMX
```

Comment: is this in code that actually compiles/works?

Comment: @agentp yes, it's proper working package.

Comment: the `AMGAS(6)` is declaring `amgas` as a length 6 array (of implicit type). I would have said the square brackets are a syntax error.. but you say it compiles..

Comment: Unless there is some other definition for those three variables, the default would be `REAL` or floating point. The curved braces or parenthesis for `AMGAS(6)` indicates that `AMGAS` is a one dimensional array of 6 elements. Not sure as to the square brackets of `VTMB[6]` but am under the impression that this is an alternative syntax for arrays with some compilers. It is also a co-array syntax as well. See https://wg5-fortran.org/N1601-N1650/N1642.pdf and see https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/bgl/papers/numrich.pdf   What compiler are you using?

Comment: Coarrays in common blocks ?!?  I think it's far more likely that the use of `[` and `]` in the snippet shown is some ancient non-standard notation.

Comment: coarrays are not permitted in COMMON blocks according to https://books.google.com/books?id=V7UVDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA405&lpg=PA405&dq=Coarrays+in+common+block&source=bl&ots=wiin-IvZvJ&sig=mKpf5VOLDikM6SZP4kvDN3Zgs_Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB95q-roXaAhWL6lMKHQdIAwsQ6AEIczAJ#v=onepage&q=Coarrays%20in%20common%20block&f=false  and looking about I am so glad to have made the transition to C many years ago. Here is what appears to be a recent FORTRAN compiler documentation http://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgi17fortref.pdf

Comment: @fireball.1 what compiler accepts this?  (gfortran flags it as an invalid use of a coarray.. )